# webkit.net browser doesn't appear

Tags: c#, .net, browser, webkit

I started using this open source project. I tried this:

```
 WebKitBrowser browser = new WebKitBrowser();
        browser.DocumentText =
    "<h1><a href=\"http://google.com\">Hello, World!</a></h1>";
```

and this:

```
WebKitBrowser browser = new WebKitBrowser();
        browser.Navigate("https://emailhunter.co/");
```

I also tried [Webkit.net opening new tabs and windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17909425/webkit-net-opening-new-tabs-and-windows) this. In first 2 cases nothing happens. I can 't even see a window. In last situation i can't compile it.

Any suggestions appritiated.

Comment: What are you hosting the WebKit control in - WPF, Windows Forms, other..?

Comment: I host them in windows forms.